# Java groupBy multiple fields

Tags: java, collections

How can i group by a json by two elements?

The sample json should be group by **uniqueAccountID**  and **uniqueAccountID**

Input Json:

```js
[
  {
    "recordType": "XAC",
    "filler": "0",
    "uniqueAccountID": "123",
    "authorizedUserCustomerID": "ab",
    "referenceStartDate": "20200224"
  },
  {
    "recordType": "XAC",
    "filler": "0",
    "uniqueAccountID": "123",
    "authorizedUserCustomerID": "ab",
    "referenceStartDate": "20200224"
  },{
    "recordType": "XAC",
    "filler": "0",
    "uniqueAccountID": "123",
    "authorizedUserCustomerID": "cc",
    "referenceStartDate": "20200224"
  },{
    "recordType": "XAC",
    "filler": "0",
    "uniqueAccountID": "999",
    "authorizedUserCustomerID": "cc",
    "referenceStartDate": "20200224"
  }
]
```

Expected result:

```js
{
  "1" : [
    {
      "recordType": "XAC",
      "filler": "0",
      "uniqueAccountID": "123",
      "authorizedUserCustomerID": "ab",
      "referenceStartDate": "20200224"
    },
    {
      "recordType": "XAC",
      "filler": "0",
      "uniqueAccountID": "123",
      "authorizedUserCustomerID": "ab",
      "referenceStartDate": "20200224"
    }
  ],
  "2" : [
    {
      "recordType": "XAC",
      "filler": "0",
      "uniqueAccountID": "123",
      "authorizedUserCustomerID": "cc",
      "referenceStartDate": "20200224"
    }
  ],
  "3" : [
    {
      "recordType": "XAC",
      "filler": "0",
      "uniqueAccountID": "999",
      "authorizedUserCustomerID": "cc",
      "referenceStartDate": "20200224"
    }
  ]
}
```

Actually I am calling a Java static inside another application so the input should be json or HashMap

The output format can be json or a list or Hashmap

Comment: "The sample json should be group by uniqueAccountID and uniqueAccountID"
You mean group by uniqueAccountID and authorizedUserCustomerID?

Also I don't really see how it is grouped by in you expected result. You group by an incremental number

Comment: Please revise your question and also post what (code) you've tried so far.